# Why does Type I error of a test occur? Is NHST too weak to tell the truth?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing

I know **Type I error** is a Stat 101 question. Recently I have noticed that Type I error of a test is too much persistent. Even if all the values are almost equal (variance is extremely low) and tested to that value (true mean), still there is nearly 5% Type I error of the test. I am frightened and curious to rethink, are the people who have banned (or skeptic about) NHST (null hypothesis significance testing) truly correct?
Let's have a look:

```
n=10000
t1err=0
set.seed(1235)
for (i in 1:n){
   x=rnorm(100, 10, 20)
   if (((t.test(x, mu=10))$p.value)<=0.05) (t1err=t1err+1) 
}
cat("Type I error rate in percentage is", (t1err/n)*100,"%")
```

It will produce roughly 5% as Type I error. Seems ok. But let's see this:

```
  n=10000
  t1err=0
  set.seed(1235)
  for (i in 1:n){
     x=rnorm(100, 10, 0.000001)
     if (((t.test(x, mu=10))$p.value)<=0.05) (t1err=t1err+1) 
  }
  cat("Type I error rate in percentage is", (t1err/n)*100,"%")
```

Each values are extremely close to 10. Still it produces about 5% Type I error. What conclusion we may draw from it? Or, am I missing something?

Comment: overwhelmed -- when you deleted this the first time, you should have mentioned you did it because it was a duplicate. (You should not post the same question twice.)